# Node not being saved when using Rules redirect

Tags: 7, rules

I need help with basic setup of Rules. I have read tuts but could not figure this one out.

I have content type A.
A is saved to system as unpublished. It saves personal information and those cant be changed anymore so users after using it get Access Denied message as they dont have permission to view it.

What i want to do with rules after node is being saved,
1. Redirects to some other internal url (any),
2. Get system message "Node creae successful".

Problem is that node after being saved with Rules module does not get saved at all. Nothing in Content, nothing in database. Without Rules everything works as intended.

Rules setup:
1. Events:
"After saving new content"

1. Conditions:
   "Content is of type" - param: Content node, Content types: A
2. Actions:
   Page redirect - url: blog
   Show a message on the site: Parameter: Message: devtest

What happens is that redirect works correctly, message does not appear (no big deal, could create node with some text on it instead of system message).
But node A does not get saved anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be redirecting before the pending node_save is called.

Try explicitly adding the action "Save Entity" under the Entities heading just before your redirect rule is evaluated. Make sure the redirect is the last action called.

[image: Add an explicit node_save action]